# Wireshark: understanding the contents of youtube video capture file

Tags: video, youtube, wireshark, flash, packet-capture

Here is [a link to a `.pcapng`](https://bitbucket.org/all3fox/pcaps/src/87492473430ab86d627519b8ab4eb614ee599359/youtube-f90c96bd7fe6ee57aded33400e461453.pcapng?at=master#) file which holds the first 30 seconds of a single youtube video. It was preprocessed in the following way:

1. I used the display filter `http.request.uri contains "crossdomain.xml"` to learn the ip address of the client and the server.
2. Using those addresses, I singled out the video stream with the following display filter `ip.addr == ip1 && ip.addr == ip2` and uploaded the resulting capture file.

The original video is [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7MLjQxGiVs).

Now the questions:

1. There are two ports used by the client: `57057` and `57058` (and the first one is used for much less traffic than the second). Why are there two ports?
2. The conversation via `57057` starts with a weird `GET /generate_204` request which gets a `204 No Content` response. Yet a few packets later there is a `GET /videoplpayback*` request which seems to be fullfilled. What does this `204 No Content` mean?

Please note I am a network noob

Comment: 204 is standard HTTP response code. It means the response does not contain any data.

Comment: @MatjazMuhic yes, but then a whole video starts to be transmitted. Isn't that wrong? I would expect a `204 No Content` mean there is no further content to be transmitted.

Comment: FYI
See [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.2.5): 204 No Content.
The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the requested variant.